# Algebraic complex number question

Tags: algebra-precalculus, complex-numbers

Find the complex number $z$ that satisfies the equation $2(z+1)=3i(z-1)$.

Expanding, I get $2z+2=3zi-3i$.

Substituting $z$ for $a+bi$:  $2(a+bi)+2=3i(a+bi)-3i$

$2a+2bi+2=3ai+3bi^2-3i$

$2a+2bi+2=3ai-3b-3i$

I'm stuck after this point, just not sure what the next step is. If someone could provide the impetus required for me to finish the problem it would be great, thanks in advance.

Comment: Equate the real and imaginary parts of the two sides.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It's a bad idea to write $z$ as $a+bi$ to solve this problem. Note that\begin{align}2(z+1)=3i(z-1)&\iff 2z+2=3iz-3i\\&\iff(2-3i)z=-2-3i\\&\iff z=-\frac{2+3i}{2-3i}\\&\iff z=\frac5{13}-\frac{12}{13}i.\end{align}